# Problem with adding Tomcat server to spring tool suite in Ubuntu?

Tags: server, java, tomcat

I ma trying to add Tomcat server in to STS but I do am not able to do it. Some times the server name doesn't appear when I try to add Tomcat by selecting it from the list, I can't type in the server name myself as well and If that step works properly (I mean when the serve name appears automatically which it should when server is selected form the list); the Finished button is grayed out in the resource page which is the last step in adding the Tomcat server to STS.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same annoying bug recently and found a solution for this. Here is the instructions,

1. Close Eclipse
2. In `{workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` delete the following two files:

   ```
   org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs

   org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs
   ```
3. Open Eclipse, Voila!

[Reference](http://crunchify.com/eclipse-how-to-fix-installing-apache-tomcat-server-issue-blank-server-name-field/)